# Junit test to find System.out.println in entire project

Tags: java

What are the different ways of finding System.out.println statement in entire project.can we write Junit to find System.out.println in entire project.

Comment: How is JUnit relevant here?

Comment: You can replace System.out to throw an Error and this would give a stack trace of where this is called.

Answer (score 2):

Why you need JUnit for this??

Use eclipse and Find string `System.out.println`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and search.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every IDE has a builtin Search functionality that you can use. If you're on Netbeans you can also use "Find usages" to find all the calls to a specific method. In Eclipse there's something similar which shows the call hierarchy.